# JS Script preventing bootstrap nav from toggling, why?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a website and each page is using a bootstrap toggle/collapse navbar. All the page this works fine except for one. For some reason on one of the pages the navbar collapses once to the appropriate screen size, but it does not drop down. However, I noticed that if I comment out a JS file I have being sourced at the bottom of the html, like so `<!--<script src="js/index.js"</script>-->` then the drop down works. What's weird is that, 2 of the other pages on the same site source the same JS script, and the dropdown still works...maybe I'm just blind. The code for the nav is as follows :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="page.html">Content</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="page.html">Content</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="page.html">Content</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="page.html">Content</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="page.html">Content</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

And there's honestly not a lot of JS, just one scroll function, and another "hover" function that I will probably move over to CSS eventually..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".business-header img").on("click", function( e ) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $("body, html").animate({ 
                scrollTop: $(".section-two").offset().top 
            }, 1500);

        });
    });

    $(".image-wrapper img").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", " 0 0 30px #F0DEBD");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).css("box-shadow", "none");
});
```

I should mention as well that each page has an identical nav. Is there something one of the functions that is causing this? I tried to search this topic on other posts, but was unsuccessful. Cheers

Comment: can you make fiddle?

Comment: this is,most of the times, due to loading the bootstrap js library more than one time.

Comment: @Elentriel I think you were right...

Comment: my pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, most times, due to bootstrap js library being loaded more than one time